Excel VBA Hallucinations With Forms Checkbox
This makes no sense.  Win11, Excel 2021 64 bit.
Create a new workbook, and add just one Check Box from the Forms Control menu.
Create two macros:
Sub Test()

    Dim Fink As Integer
    Fink = 3
    If Checkbox1 = 0 Then Fink = 0
    If ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1") = 1 Then Fink = 1
    Range("A1").Value = Fink

End Sub


Sub Testy()

    Dim Fink As Integer
    Fink = 3
    If Checkbox1 = 1 Then Fink = 1
    If ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1") = 0 Then Fink = 0
    Range("A1").Value = Fink

End Sub

Run the "Test" macro.  As expected, Fink = 0 if unchecked, and Fink = 1 if checked.
Run the "Testy" macro.  Regardless if checked or not, Fink = 3
I don't want to use ActiveX because the spreadsheet project I'm working on may go public, and some of the public fears ActiveX from strangers.  The problems I'm having boil down to this simple example.  I need to use the checkbox value in an If-Then statement, and banking on the "other state" as a failure state isn't comforting.  Any ideas what's happening?

I think you should treat Excel with a bit more respect, as much as I dislike it from time to time, it's not fully AI yet so it tends to do exactly what you tell it do it.
In this case the problem lies with your statement ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1"), which is not correct usage.  The correct syntax for checking the state of checkboxes is ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value checking for xlOff\xlOn, not ones or zeroes. Please see The Complete Guide to Excel VBA Form Control Checkboxes
If you change your code to the recommended syntax it works perfectly fine:
Sub Test()

    Dim Fink As Integer
    Fink = 3
    ' Access the checkbox value correctly
    If ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value = xlOff Then
        Fink = 0
    End If
    If ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value = xlOn Then
        Fink = 1
    End If
    Range("A1").Value = Fink

End Sub

Sub Testy()

    Dim Fink As Integer
    Fink = 3
    ' Access the checkbox value correctly
    If ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value = xlOn Then
        Fink = 1
    End If
    If ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value = xlOff Then
        Fink = 0
    End If
    Range("A1").Value = Fink

End Sub


++ nicely explained. Also one can use values instead of xlOff\xlOn. Instead of 1 and 0, one has to use 1 and -4146

Thank you Michal and Siddharth.  Once again, we've burrowed to the crux of the problem, only to find my photograph.  You might thunk I would have come across the xlOn/xlOff solution in the 97 advice sites I referenced, as they were all 0/1 or False/True.  And though the two answers completely explain the mystery of the apparent delusion, as a physicist, I'm a little uneasy living in a universe where 0=-4146.

@HorseBeforeTheCart - if it makes you feel any better, value 2 means mixed state so perhaps those values are not really supposed to have logical properties of the Boolean TRUE/FALSE, 0/1 logic.
